# Permutations of alike objects

Tags: permutations

If I have $1$ jar of $20$ balls with $10$ red, $5$ blue and $5$ yellow, $1$ jar of $30$ balls with $10$ red, $10$ blue and $10$ yellow and $1$ jar of $50$ balls with $15$ red, $20$ blue and $15$ yellow, but I can only pick three from each jar. How many permutations of balls can I get if the order is important?

As shown in this rough sketch

[image]

Attempts: $\frac{20!}{(10!\times5!\times5!)} + \frac{30!}{(10!\times10!\times10!)} + \frac{50!}{(15!\times20!\times15!)} = 7.31\times10^{21}$

Comment: @Ertxiem Is a repost, not just a duplicate!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $|P_1|$ number of permutations of the first jar. Let the permutations be $P_1={(p1,p2,p3)} $ where $p1,p2,p3$ can be red, blue or yellow. The total number of permutations is $|P_1|*|P_2|*|P_3|$ so you should multiply each of your terms not add them.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the probability part of picking one Jar from three. Which is $P(J_1)=P(J_2)=P(J_3)=\frac{1}{3}$. Then $P(J_1\cap \text{permutations of balls})+P(J_2\cap \text{permutations of balls})+P(J_3\cap \text{permutations of balls})$